# can't compile pmandel.c with mpicc

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I have installed MPICH (ver 3.0.4) on my linux machine (CentOS 6.4) for doing some parallel computation. I tried to compile "pmandel.c" (which comes with MPICH installation package as an example) to test my MPICH installation with this command :

```
mpicc pmandel.c -o pmandel.out
```

but it returns these errors:

```
pmandel.c: In function ‘main’:
pmandel.c:279: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘bind’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:115: note: expected ‘const struct sockaddr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
pmandel.c:282: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘bind’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:115: note: expected ‘const struct sockaddr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
pmandel.c:296: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getsockname’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:119: note: expected ‘struct sockaddr * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
/tmp/cclNv8nA.o: In function `exponential_complex':
pmandel.c:(.text+0x2fc2): undefined reference to `exp'
pmandel.c:(.text+0x2fd1): undefined reference to `cos'
pmandel.c:(.text+0x2fe5): undefined reference to `sin'
/tmp/cclNv8nA.o: In function `absolute_complex':
pmandel.c:(.text+0x3330): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and no output is made. I also tried with "mpic++", "mpiCC", mpicxx" ... but all to no avail.

what should I do to correct this?

Comment: These are warnings (not errors), and you could change the source code to remove them. I believe that `pmandel.out` is produced and should be runnable.

Comment: some of errors were missed in my post, i edited it. thanks

Comment: The error triggered by the linker are just missing libraries. Try to recompile with the switch `-lm`

Comment: I used the "-lm" switch but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

@Spiros is correct that you need to add -lm to your mpicc. It matters where in the command you specify it, too.

> "It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded."

see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html.

It comes after pmandel.out.

```
mpicc pmandel.c -o pmandel.out -lm
```

Alternatively, you can use the Makefile included in the mpich examples directory and just type

```
make pmandel
```

Comment: From the GCC page I referenced:
"It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded."

Comment: I should also note that mpicc is merely a convenience wrapper for an underlying C compiler, which is why the GCC rules apply.

Comment: Looking at the makefile, it seems that one should not only add `-lm` but also `-lpthread -lmpi`